# how to get ArrayLists from particular JSONObects in android?

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, arraylist

I have made an `android` activity ,In that i am parsing some data from `JSON webservice` and display it into a `ListView`,Now my problem is in my webservice each jsonObject is having Array of strings(image urls),So i dont know how to get each arrayList seperately,I have tried but got all the Arrayvalues into one arrayList,Please help me how to do seperate array per json object in android,my code and webservice is as:
[webservice link](http://dev.booking.blancatours.com/api/v1/cities)
**adapter**

```
package com.eps.blancatours.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eps.blancatours.R;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;

public class DestinationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> detArray;

    private Context mContext;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public DestinationAdapter(Context paramContext,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.detArray = list;

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(paramContext));

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.noimage)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage).build();
        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::mY rESULTANT aRRALYlIST::::::::::::"
                + list);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.detArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "static-access", "unchecked" })
    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                .getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_dest,
                    paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();

            localViewholder.destImg = ((ImageView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_dest));
            localViewholder.destName = ((TextView) paramView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_city));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();
            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }
        for (HashMap<String, Object> desti : detArray) {
            System.out.print("Desti id : " + desti.get("id"));
            System.out.print("Desti name : " + desti.get("name"));

            System.out.print("Desti program : " + desti.get("program"));
            System.out.print("Desti program_link : "
                    + desti.get("program_link"));
            System.out.print("Desti images_array size : "
                    + ((ArrayList<String>) desti.get("images_array")).size());
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> hotels = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) desti
                    .get("hotels");
            for (HashMap<String, Object> hotel : hotels) {
                System.out.print("hotel id : " + hotel.get("id"));
                System.out.print("hotel city_id : " + hotel.get("city_id"));
                System.out.print("hotel name : " + hotel.get("name"));
                System.out.print("hotel images_array size : "
                        + ((ArrayList<String>) hotel.get("images_array"))
                                .size());
            }
            localViewholder.destName.setText(detArray.get(paramInt).desti
                    .get("name"));
            imageLoader.displayImage(detArray.get(paramInt).get(0),
                    localViewholder.destImg, options);

            return paramView;

        }
    }

    static class Viewholder {
        ImageView destImg;
        TextView destName;

    }
}
```

**code**

```
ListView lv_dest;
    DestinationAdapter adapter;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONObject destinations = null;
    JSONArray imgArray = null;
    Header hdr;
    JSONArray hotelArray = null;
    Menu menu;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> destList;
    ArrayList<String> destiList, hotelList, hotel_images;
    String id;
    String name;
    String program;
    String program_link;
    String hotel_id;
    String city_id;
    String hotel_name;
    JSONArray hotel_images_array;
    Intent i;
private class GetDestinations extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DestinationsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.wait));
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            System.out
                    .println("::::::::::::::::::DESTINATIONS URL:::::::>>>>>>>>>"
                            + Const.API_DESTINATIONS);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(Const.API_DESTINATIONS,
                    BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    // yes

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                        id = c.getString("id");
                        name = c.getString("name");
                        program = c.getString("program");
                        program_link = c.getString("program_link");
                        imgArray = c.getJSONArray("images_array");
                        HashMap<String, String> Destimap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        Destimap.put("id", id);
                        Destimap.put("name", name);
                        Destimap.put("program", program);
                        Destimap.put("program_link", program_link);

                        if (imgArray != null && imgArray.length() != 0) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < imgArray.length(); j++) {
                                destiList.add(imgArray.getString(j));
                                System.out
                                        .println("::::::::::::::::::IMAGE URL:::::::::::::::::"
                                                + imgArray.getString(j));
                            }
                        }
                        hotelArray = c.getJSONArray("hotels");
                        if (hotelArray != null && hotelArray.length() != 0) {
                            for (int k = 0; k < hotelArray.length(); k++) {

                                JSONObject d = hotelArray.getJSONObject(k);
                                hotel_id = d.getString("id");
                                city_id = d.getString("city_id");
                                hotel_name = d.getString("name");

                                Destimap.put("hotel_id", hotel_id);
                                Destimap.put("city_id", city_id);
                                Destimap.put("hotel_name", hotel_name);

                                hotel_images_array = d
                                        .getJSONArray("images_array");

                                if (hotel_images_array != null
                                        && hotel_images_array.length() != 0) {
                                    for (int l = 0; l < hotel_images_array
                                            .length(); l++) {
                                        hotel_images.add(hotel_images_array
                                                .getString(l));
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        destList.add(Destimap);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            adapter = new DestinationAdapter(DestinationsActivity.this,
                    destList, destiList);
            lv_dest.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you please post json response from server url ?

Comment: @Haresh-ya haresh please see my edit.

Comment: your json response is not valid. PLease check it again..

Comment: I hope I have understood your problem correctly. IF you want to have all the results dont create a new arraylist in loop. Create it before and keep on adding things into same arrayList.

Comment: @Sweety-Wait I am editing my code and let you know,please tell me is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
String jsonStr ="[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Bodrum\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f3fde123b.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f3fde20d4.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f3fde21c6.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f43b43e37.jpg\"],\"hotels\":[{\"id\":\"3\",\"city_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Bodrum Hotel\",\"images_array\":[]}]},{\"id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Bursa\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f4ff167a8.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f4ff168e1.jpg\",\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f4ff169cb.jpg\"],\"hotels\":[{\"id\":\"4\",\"city_id\":\"2\",\"name\":\"Bursa Hotel\",\"images_array\":[]}]},{\"id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Istanbul\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f5d1927ce.jpg\"],\"hotels\":[{\"id\":\"2\",\"city_id\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Istanbul Hotel\",\"images_array\":[]}]},{\"id\":\"4\",\"name\":\"Bolu\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[\"http:\\/\\/dev.booking.blancatours.com\\/uploads\\/53d1f8f500afc.jpg\"],\"hotels\":[]},{\"id\":\"5\",\"name\":\"Trabzon\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[],\"hotels\":[]},{\"id\":\"6\",\"name\":\"Yalova\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[],\"hotels\":[]},{\"id\":\"7\",\"name\":\"Sapanca\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[],\"hotels\":[]},{\"id\":\"8\",\"name\":\"Antalya\",\"program\":null,\"program_link\":null,\"images_array\":[],\"hotels\":[]}]";
try {
     JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

     ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
     for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
          HashMap<String, Object> destiMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
          destiMap.put("id", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));
          destiMap.put("name", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
          destiMap.put("program", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("program"));
          destiMap.put("program_link", jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("program_link"));

          ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
          JSONArray imagesJsonArray = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("images_array");
          for(int j=0;j<imagesJsonArray.length();j++){
              images.add(imagesJsonArray.getString(j));
          }
          destiMap.put("images_array", images);

          ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> hotels = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
          JSONArray hotelsJsonArray = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("hotels");
          for(int j=0;j<hotelsJsonArray.length();j++){
              HashMap<String,Object> hotelMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
              hotelMap.put("id",hotelsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("id"));
              hotelMap.put("city_id",hotelsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("city_id"));
              hotelMap.put("name",hotelsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("name"));

              ArrayList<String> hotelImages = new ArrayList<String>();
              JSONArray hotelImagesJsonArray = hotelsJsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getJSONArray("images_array");
              for(int k=0;k<hotelImagesJsonArray.length();k++){
                  hotelImages.add(hotelImagesJsonArray.getString(k));
              }
              hotelMap.put("images_array", hotelImages);
              hotels.add(hotelMap);
           }
           destiMap.put("hotels",hotels);
           list.add(destiMap);
      }

      for (HashMap<String,Object> desti : list){
           System.out.print("Desti id : " + desti.get("id"));
           System.out.print("Desti name : " + desti.get("name"));
           System.out.print("Desti program : "+desti.get("program"));
           System.out.print("Desti program_link : " + desti.get("program_link"));
           System.out.print("Desti images_array size : "+((ArrayList<String>)desti.get("images_array")).size());
           ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> hotels = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) desti.get("hotels");
           for (HashMap<String,Object> hotel : hotels){
                System.out.print("hotel id : " + hotel.get("id"));
                System.out.print("hotel city_id : " + hotel.get("city_id"));
                System.out.print("hotel name : "+hotel.get("name"));
                System.out.print("hotel images_array size : "+((ArrayList<String>)hotel.get("images_array")).size());
           }
      }
} catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}


public class DestinationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> detArray;
    private Context mContext;
    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    public static ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public DestinationAdapter(Context paramContext,ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.detArray = list;
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(paramContext));
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true)
                .showStubImage(R.drawable.noimage)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.noimage).build();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return detArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return detArray.get(pos);
    }

    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        Viewholder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new Viewholder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.raw_dest, paramViewGroup, false);
            holder.destImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_dest);
            holder.destName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_city);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Viewholder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.destName.setText((String)detArray.get(position).get("name"));
        holder.destName.setText((String)detArray.get(position).get("name"));
        ArrayList<String> images = (ArrayList<String>)detArray.get(position).get("images_array");
        if(images!=null && images.size()>0){
            imageLoader.displayImage(images.get(0),holder.destImg, options);
        }
        return view;
    }

    class Viewholder {
        ImageView destImg;
        TextView destName;
    }
}
```

Comment: haresh-thank you so much but i am still confused,because i want to set it in adapter and want to display in listView,So I am not getting how to use this in adapter,can you please tell or suggest?

Comment: haresh please see my adapter,thank you in advance haresh

Comment: No,my problem is how to use that values to display in textview and image to imageview,hope you getting my problem haresh my friend.

Comment: thank you haresh,08-01 12:22:01.107: E/AndroidRuntime(24322): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 i am getting this exception now

Comment: can you tell me how to get arrayList on listItems Click so that i clan pass it to another activity?

Comment: listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                list.get(position);
            }
        });